# ASP MVC AttributeRoutes Languagetoken in URL, keep original Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using attribute routing with asp mvc 5.2.

I want the user to be able to call the urls with a language token like "de" or "en".

> mydomain/en/foo

For this I created a routeattribute with a constraint like descriped in this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints)

This works well when the locale part is at the end like:

```
[LocaleRoute("home/index/{locale}/","de)]
```

then i could call **home/index** or **home/index/de**

But when I move this to the beginning i can't omit the locale any more.

```
[LocaleRoute("{locale}/home/index","de)]
```

There i can only call **de/home/index** but **home/index**  returns a **404** Notfound. Also the constraint isn't called. It looks like the route isn't just found.

Any hints on what i'm doing wrong and what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify that the locale is an optional argument :

`[LocaleRoute("{locale?}/home/index","de")]`

On a side note, are you using different controllers for de & en ? If you use a single controller you don't need LocaleRoute and can use the default attributes (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) :

```
[RouteArea("{locale?}/home/")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    [Route("index")]
    public ActionResult Index (string culture)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also register your action with the following additional route as long as you're careful with providing a default value for culture or treating null.

```
[Route("/home/index")]
```